# Postgresql rounds float value with 5 as a last digit so unpredictable

Tags: sql, postgresql, double, rounding

So, I found that if I try to round long float value with 5 at the end, I see in the output not what I expect.

This code could sum up my tries:

```
SELECT to_char(0.7525392242956135::double precision, 'FM0.000000000000000')
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(0.7525392242956135::numeric, 'FM0.000000000000000')
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char((0.7525392242956135::double precision)::numeric, 'FM0.000000000000000');
```

And output:

```
0.75253922429561
0.752539224295614
0.752539224295613
```

BTW, `round()` brings same result.

I believe that here should be some proper explanation but unfortunately I can't find it.

Comment: There is lots of documentation on the issues around the imprecision of floating point values.

Comment: Floating point values are not precise. If you want predictable rounding, use DECIMAL (keeping in mind that decimal arithmetic is a few times slower than floating point)